Single transformer unit with identical groups of Dz windings around the same core
Background
I’m working with a three phase transformer with a 480v Delta primary and a 240v Zig Zag secondary.  However, it actually contains two primaries (combined in parallel) and two secondaries for each phase.  See first image:

I believe that I most likely will not be able to use them in parallel for my application, but I am still curious about what this configuration would be used for.
Transformer Configuration
The transformer is built with one large core that contains all three phases.
The primary side (H1, H2, H3) is connected to two identical sets of three windings wired in Delta.  The “top” delta is physically right above the “bottom” delta, and the respective windings from both are wrapped around the same sections of the core and isolated from each other (except where they meet at H1, H2, H3).
The secondary side connections: X1+, X2+, X3+, X1-, X2-, X3-, are connected to the two zigzag secondaries independently.  X1+, X2+, X3+ connect to the “top”/“+” zigzag and X1-, X2-, X3- to the “bottom”/“-“ zigzag.
The common point/neutral connections of both zigzags is not pulled out and cannot be connected or used.  See second image:

Question
We were supposed to get a standard 480v to 240v transformer, but this one was ordered instead.  I was trying to figure out if we could put the secondaries in parallel and still use it at its full power rating (93kVA).  (This is for testing three phase equipment in a lab, not for permanent installation and use in a proper application.)
I measured a phase shift when comparing X1+ -> X2+ and X1- -> X2-; X1- -> X2- was leading by 25 degrees (maybe 30deg but equipment could have been off?). Therefore, I concluded we cannot use these in parallel.
What way could these be connected internally that creates a difference in phase of 25/30deg on one since they’re both Delta to zigzag?
Also my bigger question, what kind of application would this be used for?  Why are there effectively two separate transformers on the same core to achieve the same voltage output?
And why is a Zig Zag secondary used without the neutral pulled out?

This one seems to be a phase-shifting transformer used to feed rectifier bridges.
According to the phase shift diagram, it seems to have a phase shift between secondaries, as you mention you measured it:

I can't tell what is the phase shift \$\alpha\$ just by looking, your measurements will be more reliable. Based on this value you can determine what is the number of pulses \$np\$ of the rectifier using the following equation:
$$np=\frac{360}{\alpha}$$
Sometimes high number of pulses are done using 2 different transformers, for instance, two transformer (with 2 secondaries each) with phase shift of 15° can achieve 24 pulses.
Regarding this point:

What way could these be connected internally that creates a difference in phase of 25/30deg on one since they’re both Delta to zigzag?

Using only delta or wye, one can get only 0° or 30° phase-shift between primary and secondary (and multiples of it). To achieve anything in between, there are three options of windings (you can take a look here):

zig-zag: a 'wye'-like winding with two separate parts connected in series between phases (as your picture).
Polygon: a 'delta'-like winding with intermediate connections.
Extended delta: something that is a mixture of delta and wye (the cheapest solution).

The different parts of the coils are highlighted below. Different directions means different core limbs.

Finally, to have, at the same time, similar impedance from primary to each secondary and high impedance between secondaries (low coupling), the primary needs to be split in two and connected in parallel. Allowing each part to operate independently.
